# Difference between BigQuery and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I'm new at StackOverflow and I have researched everywhere for reasons why to pick **Google BigQuery** vs **Jupyter Notebooks** for creating new variables and preparing data for Machine Learning projects. Until now, I have lots of experience doing Data Science projects with Jupyter Notebooks (love python!) but now we are working with GCP at the office and no one has been able to answer why (or when) is better to choose one over the other one.

Datalab does a great job with Jupyter Notebooks, and the data we have right now is stored part at GCS and part in Cloud SQL (I only retrieve data from there and start playing with variables).

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery is a datalake, a large database. For your problems is a data source like Cloud SQL/GCS. You need to store rows in BQ and use in your tools to write the charts/algorithms.

BigQuery cannot be compared to Jupyter Notebook, because is just two different products.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly. I've been using BigQuery to aggregate different tables and get one dataframe to train a machine learning model. On the other hand, I have used jupyter notebooks to do the same thing in my personal computer. What I don't know is when it's better to choose one over the other one. I think data size is an issue, but not so sure.

Comment: BigQuery is a data lake so it handles billions of rows, if your data size fits in your notebook than do it there, if not do in BQ. I would assume anything over 1000 rows should go into a DB.

Comment: Generally speaking it's better to pre-aggregate your data in thew database rather than do this processing in a Jupyter notebook, but as @Pentium10 says it depends on the size of data you are working with.

Comment: @MariaOliviaLihn please note that you can access BigQuery from Jupyter notebook. You obtain data from BigQuery and use it in a (local) Jupyter script. Please see, for instance, the link below. Moreover, you can run Jupyter notebook on a virtual machine within Google Cloud services.

https://towardsdatascience.com/using-jupyter-notebook-to-manage-your-bigquery-analytics-c4dc7b2a4113